# Creating a new instance of youtube library with Laravel per user

Tags: php, api, laravel, youtube

**The Project**

I'm building a social dashboard that pulls in content from youtube using Laravel along with this library https://github.com/alaouy/youtube.

**The Problem**

It's all working great when I set the consumer secret in the package config file but I want each dashboard to have it's own API key to keep rate limits etc down to each specific dashboard. At the moment, there is functionality within my app to save their key to a database and retrieve it. However I'm confused as to how I change this key based on the current dashboard. If I overwrite the config file, surely that updates for every user on the system which isn't good.

It feels like I need a new instance of the library per user and to pass in the API Key. This maybe how it works currently with Laravel under the hood but I'm not sure. If so, I'm really not sure how to approach this in a good scalable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Laravel config values on runtime and therefore override the API Key from the config file.
Try this:

```
Config::set('alaouy/youtube::KEY', 'the-api-key');
```

Comment: That was my initial thought. But, at the risk of sounding like a complete idiot, does that not mean that the config will be set for all users of the system, rather than just for that channel?

Comment: No this will only affect the current request. It will not change the config file or keep the API key in any way.

Comment: Ok cool. So if user A updates it to their key, when user B does, they aren't constantly fighting for the same variable essentially?

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem :)